# What is the purpose of Key Hash for using Facebook API on android?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm just beginning learning to use facebook's sdk for making apps and I can't quite understand the purpose of generating a key hash. Can someone explain the purpose of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Unique key to use for communication between your App and `Facebook` App

> Facebook uses the key hash to authenticate interactions between your
>   app and the Facebook app. If you run apps that use Facebook Login, you
>   need to add your Android development key hash to your Facebook
>   developer profile.

see this [Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash)